# How to scrape coinmarketcap ticker and write to file

Tags: bash, web-scraping

Could anyone point me in a direction on how to make a simple linux bash script that reads the coinmarketcap ticker and writes the prices for a few cryptocoins to a file?

For example:

read:

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/ 
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin-cash/

get data at "symbol": and at "price_usd":

write to disk:

file named (with lower case) at symbol and containing price_usd data

For the two examples, to write on disk a file called btc and containing 6415.55 with no " " and a file called bch containing 1339.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a jq solution that will let you pass the urls on the command line or read them from stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_data() {
    # if parameter is a local file just cat it (for testing) otherwise try curl
    { test -r "$1" && cat "$1" || curl -s "$1"; } | \
        jq --raw-output \
            '.[] | "\(.symbol | ascii_downcase) \(.price_usd)"'
}

process() {
    read -r filename price <<< $(get_data "$1")
    #printf "\$filename: %s\t\$price: %.2f\n" $filename $price
    echo "$price" > "$filename"
}

if [ ${#} -gt 0 ]; then # read urls from args on the command line if there are any
    while [ ${#} -gt 0 ]; do
        url="$1"
        shift
        process "$url"
    done
else # read urls from stdin
    while read -r url; do
        process "$url"
    done
fi
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!